# html form enctype on ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i have this jquery code that submits my form data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#message").hide();
$("#please_wait_box").hide();
$("#viewreseller").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    dataString=$("#viewreseller").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "view_reseller-go.php",
        cache: false,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(res){
            //$("#message").show();
            $("#please_wait_box").hide();
            $("#message").html(res);
            $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
            if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1)
            {
                window.location.href = res.substr(8);
            }
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

i need to set the *enctype* on the form to `multipart/form-data` - is this possible with my above code?

Comment: probably by doing:: $("#your_frm_id").attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data"); but why do you want to do that.. can you elaborate

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using Ajax to submit the form data, setting the `enctype` will have no effect. You are completely bypassing the form submission process that would use it.

So, let's ask if you can adapt that code to have the same effect as setting the `enctype`. The attribute has three effects on a form submission.

1. It sets the content-type of the HTTP post request. You can do this easily. `headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }`
2. It encodes the data in the form using `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` - `serialize` will never do this
3. It will include files from file inputs - `serialize` will never do this

jQuery has nothing built in to handle file uploads via Ajax. [MDN has a pretty detailed description of the process for using built in browser APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Uploading_a_user-selected_file) (note that you need a modern browser to support some of those APIs).

Since you are using jQuery, you should probably look at using a pre-written library which supports Ajax file uploads. There are [plenty of them available](http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=file+upload), but I can't recommend a specific one.